# Which approach is far better for lots ENUMs?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is for custom social network.
Any user has "Profile settings"

There about 30 settings user can change,
so
There're some categories:

- Profile settings
- SMS | Email notifications
- Authorization settings
- Security settings
- Access settings

I made several tables which keeps the settings (ENUM type)

If I drop that settings into small tables, like this (of course unique USER ID will be index'ed)

(User ID is primary key everywhere in tabs)

```
CREATE TABLE user_profile_settings ( ... ) type=MyISAM;
CREATE TABLE user_profile_notif ( ... ) type=MyISAM;
CREATE TABLE user_profile_auth ( ... ) type=MyISAM;
CREATE TABLE user_profile_security ( ... ) type=MyISAM;
CREATE TABLE user_profile_access ( ... ) type=MyISAM;
```

Then one request comes down to several tables at once, which also means some permance down.
The advantage of this is: If I neen to read only from user_profile_settings I only ask for index'ed id from that table.

The second approach is: to create one row for all user settings user has, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE all_user_config ( /***/ ) type=MyISAM;
```

It contains about 30 colums, but makes a bit harder to maintain the entire system.

The question is:
Which approach is recomended and suits for billion rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I'd recommend keeping the `ENUM` fields in one large table, so you'll only have to query and update one huge index instead of five. That's what a somewhat aged [class diagram](http://bloggineducation.wordpress.com/2010/06/07/facebook-database-schema/) claims Facebook does - or at least used to do, if the diagram is authentic.

If you're serious about your estimated user count (Facebook currently has a meager 900 million users) you may want to consider ditching relational databases such as MySQL in favor of a no-SQL solution, for example the key-value store [Cassandra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Cassandra) or document oriented [MongoDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MongoDB). They tend to scale to huge sizes and deploy to distributed environments more smoothly than relational databases.

Comment: I agree, because having a single table tends to make things more maintainable.  However, you can get into the situation where you are storing keys for the overall table as 4-bytes, but you could get away with 1-byte for individual values.  If row-length is a paramount concern, you might want to try a different approach.